# Which statement for statistical test is accurate, regarding significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

1. Statistical tests between 2 mean shows us whether the difference between sample means is significant given the inherent **sample variance**.
2. Statistical tests between 2 mean shows us whether the difference between sample means is significant given the inherent **population variance**.

Essentially, is it correct to say sample/ population variance?

Comment: To distinguish between a t test and a z test you must distinguish between knowing the population variance $\sigma^2$ and estimating the population variance with the sample variance $S^2.$ The formula for a two-sample z test requires you to specify $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2.$ The formula for a two-sample t test requires you to specify $S_1^2$ and $S_2^2.$